# How does zipflinger the new packaging tool in andorid studio work?

Tags: android, android-studio

I came across a new feature "New default packaging tool called [zipflinger](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#zipflinger)". Which is used to build your APK in android studio. i want to know what exactly is zipflinger and how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipflinger seems to be a zip utility within the existing toolchain rather than a replacement for the existing toolchain. You can find the ReadMe and source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/refs/heads/mirror-goog-studio-master-dev/zipflinger/).

From the ReadMe:

> The two main features allowing high-speed are Zipflinger's ability to edit the CD of an archive and its usage of zero-copy transfer when moving entries across archives.